# mysql create a column made of separated numbers

Tags: mysql

as the title above suggests, I'd like to create a new column in my table cointaining three double-digits numbers BUT separated by some symbols (i.e commas,tabs,points etc.).
Just an example: Column A (75,56,82) or (75-56-82) and so on.

Is it possible? What commands do I have to insert?
Thanks

Comment: Possible, Yes, Good idea .. No definitely NOT

Comment: You can use a `VARCHAR` column to store any content you want. But... do you want to treat them as real bona fide numbers later on? If that's the case, then you better have three separate columns.

Comment: What do you want to do with these 3 number once they are stored on your table

Comment: You obviously have a problem that a column named via these digits would solve. We call that an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and other members already noticed it too. How about you ask a question that relates to your real problem and not attempted solution? Your question implies you're trying to use SQL in a really, really bad way. Down the line, you'll hit a show-stopper and you'll spend way too much time fixing everything until you ultimately give up, change the storage technology for an atrocity such as MongoDB or similar crazy move.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to store all three columns as separate numbers and have a virtual column (available since MySQL 5.7) that produces the formatted value you want. For example:

```
create table t (
  id int,
  a int,
  b int,
  c int,
  f varchar(20) generated always as (concat('(', a, '-', b, '-', c,')')) virtual
);

insert into t (id, a, b, c) values (1, 75, 56, 82);

select * from t;
```

Result:

```
id  a   b   c   f
--  --  --  --  ----------
1   75  56  82  (75-56-82)
```

Comment: First of all thanks to those who attempted to offer a real help. I had better start by saying that it's not a real attempt to work on those data but it was just a basic question about the feasibility of a code. Just for sake of curiosity. In shorts, I had already divided it into 3 columns which I used later. Anyway, thanks to The Impaler for the interesting solution.